# Mill: How to add additional Resources to a module

Tags: scala, resources, mill

I have some Files out side my Module that I need to have on my classpath for testing.

Listing all possibilities (`mill resolve tests._`) I think to extend `resources` is the way to go.

I tried a lot - here my last attempt:

```
object test extends Tests {

  override def resources =
    new Sources({
      super.resources.self.map(_ :+ (millSourcePath / up / 'data / 'global / 'bpmn))
    }, 
      super.resources.ctx
    )
 ...
}
```

- Is overwriting `resources` the way to go?
- How is it done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources` is a "task of sources" [as defined here](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Tasks.html#_sources). Thus, in order to add something to the resources path you can do

```scala
override def resources = T.sources {
  super.resources() :+ PathRef(millSourcePath / up / 'data / 'global / 'bpm)
}
```